# Linux kill - Do not exit program

Tags: linux, unix

I am killing a process inside a script using kill -9 command. The process gets killed but control is exiting from the script. How do i make the following statements work after the kill command?.

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep /home/myFile | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}`

sleep 5

echo Process Stopped
```

Here both sleep and echo are not working. Can some one help?

Comment: You'll need to generate a list of the processes (before they're killed; use `| tee ps.log.$$` before the `| awk` part of your script) so that you can see why your script is being killed.  Probably, the script's path includes `/home/myFile` and so the `kill -9` signal is sent to your script as well as your target process(es).

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally killing your script too? `grep -v grep` may not be enough...

Comment: run the process that is inside the script in a sub-shell, i.e. `script cmd1; scriptcmd2; ( special_process_that_might_need_killing) ; scriptcmd_n`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

if you have `pkill` installed in your machine, you should use it

```
$ pkill -9 -f /home/myFile
```

if not, may be you can use the ancient trick instead of `grep -v grep`

```
$ kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep '[/]home/myFile' | awk {'print $2'})
```

The trick is `[/]home/myFile`.
grep'ing `[/]home/myFile` matches to `/home/myFile`,
but argument shown in `ps` does not contain `grep /home/myFile`.